# Grails event push sample application

Tags: events, grails, grails-plugin

I downloaded the Grails event push [sample](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push). Updated the plugin in BuildConfig and started the application. When I went to homepage ("/") it is displaying nothing; it is a blank page. But in the application it has general code (Gails welcome message & list of controllers) to display. Am I doing something wrong here?

There are no errors while running the app. My BuildConfig.groovy:

```
runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
runtime ":resources:1.2.7"

build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"

compile ":cache-ehcache:1.0.1"
compile ":platform-core:1.0.RC6"
compile ":events-push:1.0.M7
```

I tried to use the code provided by sample in my other projects but getting the same response: blank page. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [repository](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push) you are trying to run is source code of the plugin not the sample code.

Try [this repository](https://github.com/manishbharti/events-push-sample).

**EDIT...................................................................**

Try [this project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/378bqmbu3ad4fnt/GrailsEventsPush.zip) (Grails 2.3.7)

Problem is with tomcat version, https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/issues/55

Comment: Sorry i copied wrong link in the question. The link for sample that i wanted to provide was the same that you have provided in the answer. Home page (or in fact any page) is not displaying anything. It is just a blank page.

Comment: I tried the repository in grails 2.3.7 and it is giving errors while running and hence not showing any thing. But in grails 2.1.0(i.e., without upgrading the project) it is working fine. May be some issue with old plugins/code, try to create a fresh project and follow the tutorial/instruction given in https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/blob/master/README.md. Or try to copy past the old project code in new project(https://github.com/manishbharti/events-push-sample/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I resolved the errors by updating the version of all plugins and added grails.project.fork in BuildConfig.groovy 

How i can use this plugin in my application with current version of grails 2.3.7 I tried to use the plugin as per the guidelines provided in the plugin and am getting the same result: Blank page.

Comment: I have tried to develop a fresh project using grails events push plugin with grails 2.3.7 and grails 2.3.6 but after installing plugin the project won't run at all.

Comment: Better to raise a jira issue in grails and ask a fresh questing on issue in the project upgrade. I did not found solution of the issue. With grails 2.x events push works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will raise issue in Jira.

Comment: Thanks a lot; it is working. Will try to implement it in my app.